# escaping colon in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, escaping

Good day all, I am trying to write a script in which a command should contain the colon character ':'. Looking at [this document](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php), characters can be escaped using this character '^', but they do not mention the colon character.

The command should be:

```
iwconfig wlan0 key s:AsciiPassword
```

So in my script I have something like:

```
iwconfig $interface key s:$password
```

When I run the first command manually, it obviously does what is expected, but the second one in the script, Nothing!!!
Would appreciate any help

Update:
I cannot really produce an output because the command does not produce any.

Comment: "I have something like" ? Please update your Q with code that people can copy/paste into their terminals and get the same error messages. As is, this will be a game of 20 questions. Good luck.

Comment: The problem is not with the colon; are you sure `interface` and `password` have the correct values?

Comment: The page you link to is not about `bash`; it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

That document you link relates to windows.

In bash ; escape with '\'.

You also likely want to quote your variable expansions

I would imagine you need:

```
iwconfig "${interface}" key s:"${password}"
```

You *may* need to escape the :, though I doubt it.  If so it would be:

```
iwconfig "${interface}" key s\:"${password}"
```

Comment: You do not need to escape the colon; assuming the variable values are correct, quoting the expansions is the only thing that may make a difference.

Comment: This was my thought also; but I figured I'd include an example showing how it was done as the person is referencing a guide for the wrong platform.  Most likely its the expansion as you stated.

Comment: It's important to be explicit; otherwise, you imply it might work and you tend to get a response like "I escaped the colon and it didn't work." Try to nip such complaints in the bud.